# Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have an ajax call to JsonAction

```
              $.ajax({
                url: "/Cancel/",
                context: document.body,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.indexOf("Authorize") != -1) //indexOf not supported?
                              window.location.replace("/Account/LogOn");
                         //...
              };
```

Why is that happening?

Also i was trying to go like that:

```
var responce = result;
if (responce.indexOf("Authorize") != -1)
```

and

```
var responce = $(result);
if (responce.text().indexOf("Authorize") != -1)
```

But all the same. Ned help how to make .indexOf working.

Comment: What does your ajax call return?  Put an `alert(result)` as the first line of the success handler and see what the result actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server response is likely being interpreted as JSON, and being converted into a data object automatically by jQuery.  In that case it likely won't have an `indexOf` member, and it certainly won't be a function.

Try forcing jQuery to leave the response as text by setting the `dataType` attribute of your settings object to "text":

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/Cancel/",
  dataType: "text",
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try using this way

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/Cancel/",
            context: document.body,
            success: function (result) {
              var str=String(result);
                if (str.indexOf("Authorize") != -1) //indexOf not supported?
                          window.location.replace("/Account/LogOn");
                     //...
                     //...
          };
```